# A problem occurred during polynomial regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import time

path = "C:\\Users\\todgu\\Downloads\\삼각함수표1111.csv"
doc = pd.read_csv(path, encoding = "cp949")
doc = doc.dropna()

def sin(angle):
    y = doc.iloc[:, 3].values
    x = doc.iloc[:, 1].values
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    
    poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
    x_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)
    poly_reg.get_feature_names_out()
    len_reg = LinearRegression()
    len_reg.fit(x_poly, y)

    return len_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[angle]]))


def cos(angle):
    y = doc.iloc[:, 4].values
    x = doc.iloc[:, 1].values
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    
    poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
    x_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)
    poly_reg.get_feature_names_out()
    len_reg = LinearRegression()
    len_reg.fit(x_poly, y)

    return len_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[angle]]))


def tan(angle):
    y = doc.iloc[:, 5].values
    x = doc.iloc[:, 1].values
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

    poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
    x_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(x)
    poly_reg.get_feature_names_out()
    len_reg = LinearRegression()
    len_reg.fit(x_poly, y)

    return len_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[angle]]))

while True:
    print("<삼각함수 잘하는 AI>입니다.")
    print("이용하고자 하는 함수를 선택하세요.")
    print("[1] sin  |  [2] cos  |  [3] tan")
    func = input()
    print("각도를 입력하여 주세요.(90°이하) [뒤로가기]")
    ang = input()
    if ang == "뒤로가기":
        continue
    elif func == "1" or func == "sin":
        print(sin(ang))
    elif func == "2" or func == "cos":
        print(cos(ang))
    elif func == "3" or func == "tan":
        print(tan(ang))
    else:
        print("잘못된 입력값입니다.")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\todgu\coding\AIstudy\삼각함수.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(sin(ang))
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\todgu\coding\AIstudy\삼각함수.py", line 23, in sin
    return len_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[angle]]))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py", line 140, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 915, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1151, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_polynomial.py", line 322, in fit
    _, n_features = self._validate_data(X, accept_sparse=True).shape
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 604, in _validate_data
    out = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 948, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.
```

I was making a program that outputs the result according to the input value by learning the value of each angle of the trigonometric function.
can anyone help?
I am so tired of this.
I've tried changing the datatype, but I'm still getting errors. I have no idea why I am getting the error... ㅠoㅠ

Comment: WHERE are you getting that error?  Which line?  And, by the way, your code does nothing, because you aren't calling any functions, so we can't see how you got here.

Comment: I just added info ^0^

Comment: `ang` is a string.  You need to convert that to a float, with `ang = float(ang)`.